# How to uninstall a node.js module?

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2, nodejs, npm

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server with a Drupal 8.4 site

I want to install Node.js for my site.

1) I connected to my server with root and I entered the following command at the root of my server :

```
root@vps000000:~# curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
root@vps000000:~# apt-get install -y nodejs
```

The installation went well.

2) I'm installing now drupal-node.js :

```
root@vps000000~# npm install drupal-node.js
```

The problem is that I was wrong location for installing the module drupal-node.js. In effect it should be in the drupal site folder.

I executed the following command to uninstall it :

```
root@vps000000~# npm uninstall drupal-node.js
```

The module is uninstalled, but the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file are still there :

```
root@vps000000:~# ls
dead.letter  drupal.phar  installer_la_cle.sh  node_modules  package-lock.json
```

Here is the content of the directory node_modules :

```
root@vps000000:~/node_modules# ls
accepts             caseless             engine.io                 hawk                 media-typer        process-nextick-args  supports-color
after               chalk                engine.io-client          hoek                 merge-descriptors  proxy-addr            to-array
ansi-regex          combined-stream      engine.io-parser          http-errors          methods            qs                    tough-cookie
ansi-styles         commander            escape-html               http-signature       mime               range-parser          tunnel-agent
arraybuffer.slice   component-bind       escape-string-regexp      iconv-lite           mime-db            raw-body              tweetnacl
array-flatten       component-emitter    etag                      indexof              mime-types         readable-stream       type-is
asn1                component-inherit    express                   inherits             ms                 request               ultron
assert-plus         content-disposition  extend                    ipaddr.js            negotiator         safe-buffer           unpipe
async               content-type         extsprintf                isarray              node-uuid          send                  util-deprecate
aws-sign2           cookie               finalhandler              is-my-ip-valid       oauth-sign         serve-static          utils-merge
backo2              cookie-signature     forever-agent             is-my-json-valid     object-assign      setprototypeof        vary
base64-arraybuffer  core-util-is         form-data                 is-property          object-component   sntp                  verror
base64id            cryptiles            forwarded                 isstream             on-finished        socket.io             ws
bcrypt-pbkdf        dashdash             fresh                     is-typedarray        options            socket.io-adapter     wtf-8
better-assert       debug                generate-function         jsbn                 parsejson          socket.io-client      xmlhttprequest-ssl
bl                  delayed-stream       generate-object-property  json3                parseqs            socket.io-parser      xtend
blob                depd                 getpass                   jsonpointer          parseuri           sshpk                 yeast
body-parser         destroy              har-validator             json-schema          parseurl           statuses
boom                ecc-jsbn             has-ansi                  json-stringify-safe  path-to-regexp     string_decoder
bytes               ee-first             has-binary                jsprim               pinkie             stringstream
callsite            encodeurl            has-cors                  lodash               pinkie-promise     strip-ansi
```

I know how to install drupal-node.js in my drupal site. How to uninstall it completely from my root directory ?

Should he just do `rm -r` ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Marked [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41057802/847554)

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs

sudo apt-get remove npm
```

Also in the comments carry out some additional clean up

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node /opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules 

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you, but I just want to remove the node-drupal.js module and the node_modules folder that was installed with it. Because they were not installed in the right place.

Comment: Surely then just `sudo rm -rf node_modules`  from your root directory will do that ?

Comment: Thank you i did rm -R node_modules what serves -rf ?

Comment: I have reinstalled the module in the correct directory, but I can not configure it. Maybe you have an idea ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910412/how-to-configure-drupal-8-with-node-js-integration

Comment: `rm -rf `  enables the force remove directory . [quick reference cheat sheets](https://threenine.co.uk/linux-terminal-command-cheat-sheets/)   I have to be honest I don't really know what you mean by configuring the module ?  I thought if you are making use of Node Module it is in an application, so you make use of it in code?